# First Digits of a number

Tags: python

I want the first 9 digits and last 9 digits of a fibonocci series for an infinite loop. Running the tests individually, I get better result for the last 9 digits using modulo operator no where comparable to the first 9 digits. I ran different tests like `int(str(b)[::-1])%10**9, b/(10**(len(str(b))-9))` but still the same result. I think this happens because of number to string conversion of higher digits. Is there any other way of printing the first 9 digits without converting into a string or an efficient way with/without strings?

```
def fibby():
    a,b = 1,1
    yield [a,a]
    yield [b,b]
    while True:
        a,b = b,a+b
        yield [str(b)[:9], b%10**9]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "better results"? Which results do you obtain and what is wrong about them?

Comment: I'm not sure it'll be any more efficient than converting the whole number to a string, but you can use `math.log10()` to count the digits, and `//` to do an integer divide to fetch the most significant figures.

Comment: I mean in terms of time performance. Say, the least significant digits pop up to 10**8 in 6 seconds while the MSB takes more than 2 minutes(testing them individually). Can the MSB be a timematch for the LSB?

Comment: @DeepakKota What does "pop up to 10**8 in 6 seconds" mean?

Comment: I am solving a problem in project Euler 104. There is a better algorithm, but when I was trying to do brute force I was wondering if there can be a time match for the first digits and last digits.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: In projecteuler 104, I am brute forcing to check the the first Fibonacci number for which the first nine digits AND the last nine digits are 1-9 pandigital. When I am appending into a list all the numbers with last numbers 9 pandigital under 1 million it took around 6s. When I am appending all the numbers that are pandigital in the MSB, it took 2 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few versions and timings for getting the first 30000 prefixes. I left out the first two yields and the last digits for simplicity.

- `fibby1` is the original way just using `str(b)[:9]`.
- `fibby2` keeps track of the appropriate power of 10 to divide by.
- `fibby3` keeps the first 9 digits in `a` and `b` and the remaining digits in `A` and `B`. Compared to `fibby2`, this avoids dividing a large `b` by a large power of 10. Large numbers are only added/subtracted/compared, or multiplied with a tiny number.
- `fibby4` uses `math.log10` suggested by @therefromhere.
- `fibby5` uses the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module.

The output:

```
All agree? True
fibby1: 24.835 seconds
fibby2:  0.289 seconds
fibby3:  0.201 seconds
fibby4:  2.802 seconds
fibby5:  0.216 seconds
```

Just for comparison I also tried `str(b % 10**9)`, i.e., the last nine digits, and that took 0.506 seconds. Which is **slower** than my fast solutions for the first nine digits.

The code:

```
def fibby1():
    a, b = 1, 1
    while True:
        yield str(b)[:9]
        a, b = b, a+b

def fibby2():
    a, b = 1, 1
    div = 1
    while True:
        while True:
            front = b // div
            if front < 10**9:
                break
            div *= 10
        yield str(front)
        a, b = b, a+b

def fibby3():
    a,b = 1,1
    A,B,C = 0,0,1
    while True:
        yield str(b)
        a, b = b, a+b
        A, B = B, A+B
        if B >= C:
            B -= C
            b += 1
        if b >= 10**9:
            A += a%10 * C
            B += b%10 * C
            a //= 10
            b //= 10
            C *= 10

def fibby4():
    from math import log10
    a, b = 1, 1
    while True:
        yield str(b // 10**max(0, int(log10(b) - 8)))
        a, b = b, a+b

def fibby5():
    from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
    getcontext().prec = 7000 # enough for n = 30000
    a, b = Decimal(1), Decimal(1)
    while True:
        yield str(b)[:9]
        a, b = b, a+b

from timeit import timeit
from itertools import islice
from time import time

n = 30000
t0 = time()
list1 = list(islice(fibby1(), n))
t1 = time()
list2 = list(islice(fibby2(), n))
t2 = time()
list3 = list(islice(fibby3(), n))
t3 = time()
list4 = list(islice(fibby4(), n))
t4 = time()
list5 = list(islice(fibby5(), n))
t5 = time()
print('All agree?', list1 == list2 == list3 == list4 == list5)
print('fibby1: %6.3f seconds' % (t1 - t0))
print('fibby2: %6.3f seconds' % (t2 - t1))
print('fibby3: %6.3f seconds' % (t3 - t2))
print('fibby4: %6.3f seconds' % (t4 - t3))
print('fibby5: %6.3f seconds' % (t5 - t4))
```